# Object creation in C# question

Tags: c#, instantiation

I'm going over some c# tutorial that states the following:

"After it finds the attribute class, the compiler will check whether the attribute is allowed on a class. Then it will check for a constructor that matches the parameters specified in the attribute use. If it finds one, it creates an instance of the object by calling the constructor with the specified values"

The name of this paragraph is "compilation process", and it refers to the way the compiler handles attributes. I'm sorry for the ignorance, but shouldn't instances be created at run time?

Thanks.

Comment: Searching for that quote returns exactly 1 result: this question. Where did you get it from?

Comment: It sounds like compiler here is being used as a synonym for "code the compiler generates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes define metadata for classes -- every instance of the class (i.e. object) will share the same attribute values. This metadata is stored alongside the type definition, which is calculated once at compile time from the source files.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are attributes that also [affect **the compiler**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx), I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler **did** instantiate them when compiling. So what?

Comment: I didn't know that the compiler instantiates objects.

Comment: Sounds rather unlikely. I doubt that the compiler instantiates attributes(i.e. it calls the constructor of a user defined attribute).

Comment: how would a compiler instantiate an object??

Comment: @miguel - compile the class, then fire up .NET and instantiate it? O_o

Comment: that is not the compiler instantiating an object. that is the runtime.

Comment: @miguel - well, I don't think that an object can **exist** outside the runtime, so it's kinda pointless to think otherwise. Of course the runtime would be involved. But it would be the compiler that started it all. Is there a point to this splitting of hairs? I think that the question was about whether an instance of an object can get created as a part of the compilation process (regardless of how it was made).

Answer (score 1):

There is a "compilation" process that generates an intermediary code which is interpreted using .NET framework.

That's why they are talking about compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler only creates metadata which describes the attribute construction and assignments to its properties.
The attribute itself is only instantiated at the time you use reflection to list attributes. I think each call to reflection creates a new instance of that attribute.

And I think there is a way(related to reflection only contexts) to check the attribute directly from the meta without instantiating it at all.